# Mercurial: Meld launching issues in Mac OS X and Meld not detected in Mercurial

Tags: macos, mercurial, meld

I installed `meld` using Macports following the instructions in [here](http://www.codez.co.uk/2014/02/meld-on-mac-osx-mavericks-10-9/). I even installed `XQuartz` as well.

**Problem is**: every time I tried to launch meld from command line, I received a bunch of errors warning messages below, and somehow the meld window still launched. I would like to get rid of these error messages because they make me feel really unsafe using `meld` if these error msgs pop up every time I try to launch. Is there a solution to this ?

```
Couldn't bind the translation domain. Some translations won't work.
'module' object has no attribute 'bind_textdomain_codeset'

** (process:622): WARNING **: Trying to register gtype 'GMountMountFlags' as enum when in fact it is of type 'GFlags'

** (process:622): WARNING **: Trying to register gtype 'GDriveStartFlags' as enum when in fact it is of type 'GFlags'

** (process:622): WARNING **: Trying to register gtype 'GSocketMsgFlags' as enum when in fact it is of type 'GFlags'
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gobject/__init__.py:115: Warning: attempting to add an interface (GtkEditable) to class (HistoryFileEntry) after class_init
  type_register(cls, namespace.get('__gtype_name__'))
```

**Second question is**: I want to be able to use `meld` as a visual diff tool in Mercurial. And I have the following configurations in my `.hgrc` file. But somehow I kept getting an error saying `No visual diff tools were detected.` Am I missing something in the `.hgrc` file ?

```
[ui]
merged = meld
[tortoisehg]
vdiff = meld
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the error messages are GTK-related and nothing to worry about (as long as you can see the graphical diff).

To use meld as a merge tool, you need 'merge = meld', not 'merged = meld'.

I'm afraid I don't know too much about launching a difftool from tortoisehg.
However, to launch meld from the commandline, I activate the 'extdiff' extension.

```
[extensions]
extdiff =

[extdiff]
meld =
```

That allows you to launch meld using 'hg meld' (which will take the same arguments as 'hg diff').

Comment: What do you mean by GTK-related ?

Comment: GTK is the graphical toolkit meld uses to render its user interface.